# How to localize InfoPlist custom variables which were read from .xcconfig file?

Tags: localization, xcconfig

I want to localize urls which i was defined in .xcconfig file. I'm trying to localize it inside InfoPlist.strings, but don't reach success... Localization for app name works, and environment variables (URLS) was readed successfully.

```ini
/* Bundle name */

"CFBundleName" = "GetFetch";
"TWO_URL" = "$(ERROR_URL)";
"GET_LIST_URL" = "$(ERROR_URL)";
```

```
GET_LIST_URL = https:/$()/804fe7d0@-4ead-419a-97c0-cc76a33615e5.mock.pstmn.io/get
ERROR_URL = https:/$()/804fe7d@—-4ead—419a-97c0-cc76a33615e5.mock.pstmn.io/
TWO_URL = https:/$()/804fe7d@-4ead-419a-97c0-cc76a33615e5.mock.pstmn.io/product
```

[image]

[image]

Someone have solutions for that?